# Limit selectable rows in ag-grid-react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Can I limit the number of selectable rows in ag-grid when `rowSelection:multiple`?

Selected rows are submitted to a backend API that gets overloaded above a specific size. My goal is to restrict the number of selected rows to 25 at any given time.

The [Row Selection docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/) don't mention a technique for limiting selected rows. The closest I can find is the ability to [ignore filtered rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#select-everything-or-just-filtered).

If there isn't native support for limiting selected rows, is there an event handler I can fire to limit additional selection? There are `onRowSelected` and `onSelectionChange` events, but I can't figure out what to put in them to deny further selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `onSelectionChanged` callback to see if too many rows are selected and if so, deselect any rows.

```
onSelectionChanged: params => {
    const selectedRows = params.api.getSelectedNodes();
    let selectedRowsCount = selectedRows.length;

    if (selectedRowsCount > 3)
    {
        while (selectedRowsCount > 3)
        {
            params.api.deselectNode(selectedRows[selectedRowsCount - 1])
            selectedRowsCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

The above function will continue deselecting rows after a selection has been made until you have only 3 selected rows (obviously change this to 25 for your case).

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-aezbmm?file=index.js).

Comment: That's nearly it, thank you. When I select consecutive rows it behaves as expected. If I select non-consecutive rows the final selected row changes unpredictably.

Comment: what do you mean the selected row changes unpredictably?

Comment: Disregard. The problem I had was related to holding down Shift for multiselect. Thanks again!